# How do you use ffmpeg npm package with svelte?

Tags: npm, ffmpeg, svelte

I want to use ffmpeg with svelte but I don't know how, I tried adding it to package.json but it didn't work (Running linux)

Comment: It would help if you clarified what you mean by "it didn't work". If you got an error message, please include the full text of the error in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the [ffmpeg npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffmpeg)? This package is only supported when running from Node, it does not work inside a browser. If you need to use this package, you'll need a Node server that uses ffmpeg that the Svelte app communicates with.

The package [@ffmpeg/ffmpeg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg) can be used inside a browser that supports WebAssembly. It doesn't really interact with a front-end framework like Svelte, so you can call it from any Svelte event handler function that you'd like. You should look at [their sample code](https://ffmpegwasm.netlify.app) to get started.